# Bypass security of HTML import

Tags: javascript, angular, security, sanitization, sanitize

I am importing an [HTML snippet](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) from a third party and embedding it into some placeholder outside my Angular 7 application. There's one link starting with `javascript:` inside the snippet that will be prefixed with `unsafe:` by Angular which breaks its functionality.

The [DOMSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) of Angular only seems to provide a way to bypass security for HTML strings. However, in below method I'm just reading the DOM node and appending it to a different destination. So I'd need to have a solution for a DOM node.

According to my research, the inserted nodes are OK directly after the `appendChild` call, but a few ms after that Angular adds the `unsafe:`.

How can I bypass security for DOM nodes?

```
 private insertPart(componentImportLinkId: string, targetSelector: string): void {
    try {
      const linkElement: any = document.getElementById(componentImportLinkId);
      const componentContent = linkElement.import;
      const componentTemplate = componentContent.querySelector('template');
      const importedComponentTemplateClone = document.importNode(componentTemplate.content, true);
      const appendToElement = document.querySelector(targetSelector);
      appendToElement.appendChild(importedComponentTemplateClone);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`PortalLayoutComponent.insertPart: Can not insert '${targetSelector}'`, e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just a random guess, the DOMSanitizer link you provided also links to [`bypassSecurityTrustScript()`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrustscript), did you try that? That said, regardless if this works or not, you must be 200% sure that the data you're importing from this 3rd party is "safe".

Comment: @HamZa The `bypassSecurityTrustScript` also expects a string as parameter value, but what I have is only a DOM node. I'm 200% sure that the HTML is "safe", it's directly coming from a portal of the customer :-)

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports), HTML Imports are obsolete. The article you linked to suggesting to use them is from 2013 (5 years old as of this writing). If you cannot convert to a standard HTML tag, then probably you should use an iframe and `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl`. Read the Angular docs about [trusting safe values](https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis).

Comment: Can you please provide a stackblitz demo of what exactly you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You could get a String value of your DOM-Node by calling outerHTML() on componentTemplate